# Multiheaded Model in Keras - error while merging

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I try to implement a multiheaded model with a variable number of inputs of 1D data, which has a length of sps each.

So I define the Input in the loop which is later merged in a single model.  And get the error

> ```
> dense = (Dense(locChannels, activation=locActivation, input_shape=merged.output_shape)) (merged)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'output_shape'

If I remove the input_shape-parameter from the dense object I get the following:

> UserWarning: Model inputs must come from `keras.layers.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to your model was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer
>   flatten_1.
>   Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = keras.layers.Input(shape)`.

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

I think I should clarify how my data looks. Maybe I habe an error in my structure.

locChannels is the number of different Features I have. Every feature is 1D and has exact sps samples in it. 
The desired output is one-hot-coded-array .

```
differentModels = list()

for index in range (0,locChannels):
    name = 'Input_'+str(index)
    visible = Input(shape=(sps,1), name=name)
    cnn1 = Conv1D(filters=8,kernel_size=2, activation=locActivation) (visible)
    cnn1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2) (cnn1)
    cnn1 = Flatten()(cnn1)
    #print(visible)
    differentModels.append(cnn1)

merged = Concatenate()(differentModels)
dense = (Dense(locChannels, activation=locActivation, input_shape=merged.output_shape)) (merged)

for index in range (2,locLayers):
    dense = (Dropout(rate=locDropoutRate)) (dense)
    dense = (Dense(locChannels, activation=locActivation, input_shape=(locChannels,))) (dense)
output = Dense(units=locClasses, activation='softmax')(dense)

model = Model(inputs=differentModels, outputs= output)
```

Comment: You need `Concatenate()(differentModels)`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I changed that but get a new error, as stated above

Answer (score 0):

I just found out, what my mistake was. 
In the line

```
model = Model(inputs=differentModels, outputs= output)
```

Input need to be the head, or Input layer, not the last one.  So the following is working as expected:

```
inputheads = list()
myinputs = list()

for index in range(0,features):
    input_a = Input(shape=(sps,1),name='Input_'+str(index))
    cnn1 = Conv1D(filters=8,kernel_size=2, activation='selu') (input_a)
    cnn1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2) (cnn1)
    cnn1 = Flatten()(cnn1)
    inputheads.append(cnn1)
    myinputs.append(input_a)

merged = Concatenate() (inputheads)
dense = Dense(20)(merged)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(dense)
model = Model(inputs=myinputs, outputs=predictions)
```